# Using the built-in price update javascript for custom entity options

Tags: price, javascript

Since none of the Magento built-in product types suit my needs, I am using custom entities to represent product options on the product page. These are not custom options, attributes, configurable products, or any of that, so forget about all that.

There are a number of features I'd like to keep, one of which is updating the price display as the user toggles various options.

I'm making a guess here, but I figure I should be able to simply supply my own configuration when making a call such as:

```
var opConfig = new Product.Options(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```

Where `$this->getJsonConfig()` is replaced with a method that defines my own configuration based on the options I am using. Assuming I use the same patterns found in `view.phtml` and it's descendants, is this all that is essential to updating the price display? Am I better off simply writing my own JS methods to handle this?